# HTML--different webpages have different Xpaths? How to scrape within same company's webpages?

Tags: html, selenium

Dont truly know how to convey my problem but each webpage within a database I'm scraping has variations within the Xpaths of the thing I want to collect. How can I effectively scrape webpages when their **exact** locations vary by a few places each page?

Using Python 3.6 and Selenium.
I want to use CSS selectors because someone said they allow for 'scraping by adjacency' but frankly IDK how and no tutorials are really saying how to CSS select from adjacent variables

```
    enter codelet email = '';
let contacts = document.querySelectorAll('div.contact-section');
for (let i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
  if (contacts[i].getAttribute('automation-id') === 'contact-true-owner') {
    ele = contacts[i]
  }
}
let links = ele.querySelectorAll('address > a')
let last = links.length - 1;
email = links[last].innerText; here
```

Comment: Update the question with the relevant HTML and your code trials

Comment: @undetectedSelenium sup,  unfrtunately I cannot show you the HTML 'cause it's 3rd party sub website we use.  ALSO like I said, each webpage that I scrape has a slightly different Xpath, so 1 example of HTML will be different from another. Is that helpful?

Comment: @undetectedSelenium what would you advise? I can't show you the HTML because it's different for each webpage,